# I cannot access an internal website from a single (ubuntu) machine in our LAN

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking

I have an internal website that cannot be seen by one of the Ubuntu machines on our LAN.  Here's the setup:

- M1 - Windows server hosting the site.
- G8 - Ubuntu machine that cannot see the M1 site.
- Dev - Windows dev machine used as a control.

---

- Dev can always see the website on http://M1/
- Dev can always successfully ping M1 to get M1's correct IP address of: xxx.xxx.xxx.31

---

- G8 can see the website on M1 for a minute or two after rebooting.  After that point, G8 cannot see the M1 website.
- G8 can see other websites on the LAN just fine, at other machines such as M2, M3, etc.
- G8 can always successfully ping M1 to get M1's correct IP address of: xxx.xxx.xxx.31
- G8 cannot curl the M1 site.  Nor can it wget it.
- G8 CAN curl and wget sites on other LAN servers such as M2, M3, etc.
- G8 cannot telnet to the M1 site port.  It just says 'Trying xxx.xxx...' and is stuck.

G8 seems to be the only machine on our LAN with this problem.  It would seem to be some startup thing that's causing the issue, since it works for a couple of minutes post-reboot.

Here is a screenshot of 'top' from G8: https://www.screencast.com/t/hUQr9FsoFrW

I've compared 'ps -aux' output from just after a reboot (when G8 can see M1) and just after G8 stops seeing the M1 website.

Does anyone have any useful ideas for troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is a firewall running on either box? M1 & G8?

Comment: This sounds very much like a firewall dropping traffic. Check the firewall on both M1 and G8 *AS WELL AS* any firewall between the two boxes. Successful pings helps to ensure that the network routes are viable and to a degree there is connectivity, which definitely implies some form of firewall, or even a blacklist/whitelist type issue.

Comment: Duplicate IP address for G8? Strange routing table entries on G8 or M1? Or anywhere in-between. When G8 can no longer access the website on M8, can it still ping it?

Comment: @David - I just tried turning off the firewall on M1.  Same result from G8.  I don't think that G8 is running a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, guys!

@roaima - you got it!  I had a duplicate IP on the LAN!  M1 had another device using it's IP address.  I found it by looking through the 'connected devices' list and spotted the duplicate entries.  Once there, it was easy enough to change over the IP address of the miscreant and now G8 can always see the site on M1.